# Size of parent planet in the sky from a tidally locked moon

Tags: moons, astronomy, tidally-locked

**TLDR:** Can anyone explain to me (like I am five and very bad at math, the latter of which I actually am) how to determine the size of the parent gas giant in the sky of my moon?

EDIT: I am asking for the *planet size* in the sky of the moon, not the size of the moon in the planet's sky.

---

Thanks to *Starfield* (I know it's not scientifically accurate, but the visuals are lovely) I've fallen in love with the idea of a ringed parent planet in the sky of my world, for which the route of a tidally locked moon orbiting the parent gas giant with rings seems the most plausible to me. Besides, that gets me interesting day-night and seasonal cycles, which is intriguing.

I'm struggling with envisioning or calculating how big that parent planet would be in the sky of my world, mainly for storytelling and art purposes. I've been working off Saturn and Titan (though the actual gas giant would be different since it needs to be in the habitable zone of its star, which we're just assuming it is) and, using Universe Sandbox, tried moving Titan to a distance that gives me 8.73 days per orbit/rotation, so one "day" = 8.73 Earth days and same for the nights (from my understanding, please correct me if that's wrong!) In Universe Sandbox, that happens at 0.00339 AU (507136.7817km, 3151201866.72335005miles).

I used a screenshot [from this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usYC_Z36rHw&ab_channel=yetidynamics) in which Saturn is as close to Earth as the Moon and have tried to scale Saturn to 0.00339 AU from "Titan" instead:
[image]

However, this method doesn't seem right? I searched for scientific guesses on how Saturn looks from Titan (without the atmosphere in the way). [The ESA](https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Images/2003/04/Saturn_as_seen_from_Titan_with_Cassini_just_visible) has [different pictures](https://www.space.com/16130-titan-landing-saturn-moon-huygens-pictures.html) which are more or less the same scale, but when I use the method I mentioned above, I get this [image] which is *a lot* smaller than the ESA renditions, so my method can't be correct.

Some of my thoughts/hopes for the moon and gas giant:

- The moon is big enough to support Earth-like life but smaller than Earth. Less gravity than Earth, higher atmospheric pressure and density.
- Tidally locked but has seasons. I'm thinking similar to Saturn (and consequently Titan), so both the parent gas giant and the moon are tilted slightly on their axes.

Comment: Planet is $d_P$ kilometers across. The satellite is at a distance of $r_S$ kilometers from the planet. The angular size of the planet seen from the satellite is $2 \arctan (d_P/2r_S)$. For example, Saturn has a diameter of about 120,000 km. The question gives the radius of the orbit of the satellite as 0.0034 a.u. or 508,633 km. The angular size of Saturn seen from that distance is 0.235 radians or 13° 30′, or about 27 times as large as the full moon in the sky of Earth.

Comment: @AlexP I've seen that formula before and have tried to apply that to a random picture of the moon in the sky, but it appeared far too big to me--that's probably a me problem, though, or I used wrong scaling. I'll try to find a program that lets me simulate the sky and increase the moon through that. I think it's possible in US... Thanks for the calculation and formula explanation!

Comment: If you want to know how large the object would appear in a photograph, you need to know the [angle of view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view_(photography)) of the photocamera, which depends on the focal length of the lens (and the size of the photosensitive recording element). (Note that the photocamera can be virtual not physical, as for example in the case of a realistic painting, which shows a scene *as if* it would have been imaged by a photocamera, except the camera was in the mind of the painter). I have photos where the moon is huge, and photos in which it is tiny...

Comment: Voting to keep closed as a duplicate. The mathematics of apparent size don't change just because you're asking about a bigger sphere than the sphere contemplated in the original question. Apparent size is a function of the diameter of the visible sphere and its distance from the observer.

Comment: @AlexP I realised that at some point after my original comment, so I used a different picture which had that information. Thanks again